# How to convert the data into html reading from data base

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing an application in which I have used the editor so when the user submit the data the data was send to the sql server in HTML format.

```
<p><strong><em>fghfghfghfghfghfghfgdfxvbc</em></strong></p> <ol> <li>.
```

it will not converted in to html tags.
I'm using Asp.net Mvc.

The code is as follow:

Comment: The code project editor has converted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding raw HTML to a page in ASP.NET MVC, you need to use

```
@Html.Raw("your html string here")
```